# How to add a common prefix/suffix to a list of strings?

Tags: elisp

How to add a common prefix/suffix to a list of strings?
For example:

From `("abc" "123" "xy")`

To `("pre_abc" "pre_123" "pre_xy")`

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
(mapcar (lambda (c) (concat "pre_" x)) '("abc" "123" "xy"))
```

Answer (score 1):

In Emacs without third-party libraries you use [`mapcar`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mapping-Functions.html) function to apply a function to every element of the list, as [@sds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22623203/596361) have shown. However if you program in Elisp heavily, i recommend installing 2 third-party libraries, [`dash.el`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el) for list manipulation and [`s.el`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el) for string manipulation. These libraries introduce a huge amount of auxiliary functions with a consistent naming scheme. `dash.el` also have [anaphoric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphoric_macro) versions for many functions, which makes code even less verbose. So to add a prefix for every string in a list you could use [`--map`](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el#-map-fn-list) and [`s-prepend`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el#s-prepend-prefix-s) ([`s-append`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el#s-append-suffix-s) for suffixes):

```
(--map (s-prepend "x" it) '("a" "b" "c")) ;; => ("xa" "xb" "xc")
```

Answer (score 0):

The operation to prepend is `(concatenate 'string <strings ...)`

So you could achieve your goal with

```
(cl-loop
 for item in '("abc" "123" "xy")
 collect (concatenate 'string "pre_" item))
```

A more general way to compose/generate strings would be to use format

using format would be

```
(cl-loop
 for item in '("abc" "123" "xy")
 collect (format nil "pre_~S" item))
```

Note using `cl-lib` package